# VB3 application that runs on 32-bit but not on 64-bit

Tags: windows, ms-access, vb6, 32bit-64bit

I have a VB3 application that works on Windows XP and win 7 32-bit version but doesn't work on win 7 64-bit version. Can anyone explain why? I know that drivers have the same behavior, but this is not my case it's just a simple application that reads from Access database. And as far as I know most 32-bit applications work on 64-bit architecture.

Comment: The most likely reason is that it's a 16-bit application, not a 32-bit program.  This is especially the case for VB3.

Comment: [Visual Basic 4.0 (August 1995) was the first version that could create 32-bit as well as 16-bit Windows programs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visual_Basic#Timeline_description).

Comment: so if it's a 16-bit app , it will work on 32-bit architecture and not on 64-bit ?

Comment: If you indeed used VB3 (as opposed to e.g. VB6), [then it will not](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/896458).

Comment: Windows 64 no longer supports 16-bit applications. Windows 16 bit has been dead for 25+ years now, and they finally dumped the compatibility shims for it.

Comment: thanks all ... very helpful

Comment: You can set up a virtual machine in Windows 7 Pro and Ultimate. Install this with any 32-bit Windows version, and can run your application here. You access the VM with a normal Remote Desktop connection.

Comment: It has nothing to do with "compatibility shims."  Such 16-bit programs don't run because there isn't any 16-bit WoW subsystem on 64-bit Windows.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The most likely reason is that it's a 16-bit application, not a 32-bit program.  This is especially the case for VB3, which supported only 16-bit programs, as "gserg" noted.